# Get ruby dungeon to repeat back player name

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to expand upon Peter Cooper's dungeon game in Beginning Ruby and I want the game to address the player by name at each room and then ask them where they will go to make the game more interactive. I keep getting this error though:

> dungeon.rb:82:in `<main>': undefined method`name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

So the main parts I've added to try to make this work are Dungeon initialize (lines 4-13)

```
def initialize
player_name = ""

until !player_name.empty?
  puts "Enter your name!"
  player_name = gets.chomp
end

@player = Player.new(player_name)
@player.name = player_name
@rooms = []
end
```

The line in question that creates the error is this:

```
    my_dungeon.add_room(:largecave, "Large Cave", "#{@player.name}, you find yourself in a large cavernous cave. To the west is a small aperture", {:west => :smallcave})
```

Full code is here:
[Ruby Dungeon Code](https://github.com/heylittlehouse/Ruby-Dungeon/blob/master/code)

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted to use

```
my_dungeon.player.name
```

instead of

```
@player.name
```

in rooms addition method calls(since `player` has been defined for `Dungeon` instance).

So just use these lines instead of ones you currently have:

```
my_dungeon.add_room(:largecave, "Large Cave", "#{my_dungeon.player.name}, you find yourself in a large cavernous cave. To the west is a small aperture", {:west => :smallcave})
my_dungeon.add_room(:smallcave, "Small Cave", "#{my_dungeon.player.name}, you find yourself in a small, claustrophopic cave. To the east is a small aperture", {:east => :largecave}
```

By the way, you set name in initialize method, so there is no need for `@player.name = player_name`. And it is simpler to read `while player_name.empty?` instead of `until !player_name.empty?`, consider following refactoring:

```
  def initialize
    player_name = ""

    while player_name.empty?
      puts "Enter your name!"
      player_name = gets.chomp
    end

    @player = Player.new(player_name)
    @rooms = []
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! it was very informative.  One more question because this also confused me about the player name bit.  What is the relationship between the attr_accessor :name and @name in the Person class of this program.  Are both necessary? Do they work together somehow?

Comment: @heylittlehouse no, they don't work together. You can easily replace `attr_accessor :name` with `attr_reader :name`(you need reader because you use `my_dungeon.player.name`, it gives you an ability to read player's name basically).